# Disabling middleware locally

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

With AllowAnonymous added as a filter to `AddMvc` I can force the .net core backend to allow a pass through the Authorize Attribute. This works great.

However I have authorization middleware which I would like to disable locally, but not on the staging server. How could this be achieved? A config that is only available on my local machine? I have the problem where, when I deploy this config is also deployed.

Is there a best practice for this? I am now force to comment out my middleware, which seems less than ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways thats i can think of currently

the first is use the IHostingEnvironment in the startup with the IsDevelopment() method to check if the current setup is running on prod or develop

the second is use appsettings and have one for dev and prod and have a toggle in the appsettings that disables the auth

Comment: I added a more global config file and use the `appsettings.{NAME}.json` naming to get what I wanted, a boolean that took care of both settings, and the configuration is of course available in my middleware. Thanks for pointing in the right direciton.